# Bib file in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I have a problem regarding the font of my bib file in TeXstudio. Here is a sample:

```
@article{DBLP:journals/mp/Vaidya90,
author    = {Pravin M. Vaidya},
title     = {An Algorithm for Linear Programming which Requires $O(((m+n)n^2)
           + (m+n)^{1.5})n)L)$ Arithmetic Operations},
journal   = {Math. Program.},
volume    = {47},
pages     = {175--201},
year      = {1990},
}


@book{Kroening:2008:DPA:1391237,
author = {Kroening, Daniel and Strichman, Ofer},
title = {Decision Procedures: An Algorithmic Point of View},
year = {2008},
edition = {1},
publisher = {Springer},
}
```

The font of all keywords are consistent with the font size of the editor but not inside the parentheses. The font is very small. I do not know how can I change the font size.

Comment: Could you eloborate a little more on this? Which OS are you on and which version of TeXstudio do you use?
I have just displayed your sample file on my machine (Kubuntu 14.04/TeXstudio 2.10.2) and I can't spot any problems.

Comment: You  could change the font for the editor part of TeXstudio `Options / Configure TeXstudio / Editor`. But I would also suggest that you edit your .bib file with a program like `Jabref`. The used font however has nothing to do with the visual appearance of your final LaTex document.